# Do Miners have to get below the Target or the Bits value?

Tags: difficulty, mining-technical-details

You get a specific Target value when you divide the maximum Target by the Difficulty.

But when you convert the Target in to the Bits format, you're only taking the first 3 bytes of the Target and losing some accuracy.

For example:

```
Difficulty: 166851513282.78

Original Target: 0x696f3ffffffe0c000000000000000000000000000000000
Target -> Bits: 0x180696f4
Bits -> Target:  0x696f4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So when a Miner is trying to get a low enough hash value for the block, are they trying to get below the **Bits** value or the **Target** value?

Answer (score 2):

Below the target value that corresponds to the bits field in the block.

Comment: So the Bits field is ultimately a short (and slightly less accurate) representation of the Target, just for the purposes of having a representation of the Target in the block header?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming Bits is always rounded up?